# Laravel 5.1 redirect after auth

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I am using laravel 5.1 and have a route similar to:

```
Route::get('/{id}/write-review', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ItemController@writeReview']);
```

The problem I have is that when someone goes to this page (when not logged in) they get redirected to login, which is fine, but then redirected to the `$redirectPath` set in *AuthController.php*. I would like them to be redirected back to the review page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The intended redirect function will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being caught by the authentication filter. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

```
 return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
```

I think i found the problem route {id}/write-review must be under the web middleware

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::get('/{id}/write-review', ['uses' => 'ItemController@writeReview']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am quite new to Laravel and do not know where this is meant to go. I am using the built in login so there is no login function in my AuthController.php file. Where do I put the line you suggested?

Comment: can you post the login function from AuthController ?

Comment: There is no login function from AuthController. Laravel deals with this for you. In AuthController there is: protected $loginPath = '/login'; protected $redirectPath = '/admin/account'; __construct and validator.

Comment: When I wrap the route in 'Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {' I get  'Class web does not exist'. Is this for laravel 5.1?

Comment: my mistake it is laravel 5.2 laravel 5.1 has no web middleware.  I have test the build in laravel 5.1 login and it uses redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()); after successful logins. Is your session driver working normally ?

Comment: Sorry about delay, was away. I believe my session driver is working normally. I can log in to the site and using Auth::check seems to work as it should. Where would I check to see if my install has 'redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());'?

Comment: you can check it at /vendor/laravel/framework/llluminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUser.php. Check the functions postLogin and handleUserWasAuthenticated. '   return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());' must be in the handleUserWasAuthenticated function. Also you can always implement your own login method